# Google Cloud Shell Editor not loading resources

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, editor, google-cloud-shell

I've experienced that Google Cloud Shell Editor doesn't load, it keeps on loading resources forever. I've tried to restart my instance multiple times. I've changed projects, trying the boost feature, I've even reset my home directory, but nothing works. I've experienced this before and then it has resolved by itself after a few days. But that is not an optimal solution since I'm a frequent user of the editor. Today I experienced it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a solution I want to share with others who experience the same problem. The reason for not loading resources is an authentication problem. If you open dev tools > console in your browser you will see you get multiple 405 errors. I solved this by running `gcloud init` in the terminal and then reload the editor.

Comment: If this doesn't work, clear cookies and login again.

Comment: @nDaota Didn't work for me unfortunately. I can't download or upload anything to Cloud Shell Editor :(

Answer (score 17):

For others who might have this problem: turning off my AdBlocker solved this issue.

Comment: Worked like charm!

Answer (score 6):

To resolve the issue, I needed to do all these steps:

1. Disable Ad Blocker for cloud.google.com if you have it running in Chrome.
2. Sign out of console.
3. Clear Cookies.
4. Reload page: https://console.cloud.google.com
5. Login and select project

Each step was recommended in other answers and comments. Thanks!

My issue was related to Authentication. The shell authenticates and works fine but the editor hangs. The errors are visible in browser dev-tools.

Should log a defect if others are seeing it.

```
VM148:1 GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=sessionState&login_hint=*redacted*&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fssh.cloud.google.com 500
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the same issue. After clearing the cookies and making sure Ad Blocker is disabled, I still wasn't able to access it because I was in incognito mode.

Had to go to normal browser mode and now it opens as expected

[image]